# Color Picker In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, material-ui, color-picker, gameobject

I am making a game where there is a color picker to change the color of an GameObject where clicking on a color in the button should take back the color it points though inside the buttons and pass it to the material of the game object. It mostly works fine but there is some issue with the cursor position which brings in a different color, but not the color to which it is pointed. Requesting help.

```cs
   public RectTransform Rect;
    public Text TestText;
    public Texture2D ColorTexture;
    public GameObject Plane;

 public void PickColor()
    {
        

        Vector3 imagePos = Rect.position;
        float globalPosX = Input.mousePosition.x - imagePos.x;
        float globalPosY = Input.mousePosition.y - imagePos.y;

        int localPosX = (int)(globalPosX * (ColorTexture.width / Rect.rect.width));
        int localPosY = (int)(globalPosY * (ColorTexture.height / Rect.rect.height));

        float x = Input.mousePosition.x * (ColorTexture.width / Rect.rect.width);
        float y = Input.mousePosition.y * (ColorTexture.width / Rect.rect.width);

        Color Col = ColorTexture.GetPixel(localPosX, localPosY);
        TestText.color = Col;

        SetActualColor(Col);

    }
    void SetActualColor(Color Col)
    {
        TestText.color = Col;
        Plane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Col;

    }
```

Comment: Could you show a picture of the cursor selecting the wrong color?

Comment: [image](https://ibb.co/XXTY1VS) This is the link to the image the circle is the cursor position and the color on the text is the color that is returned, thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're using a custom cursor. Do you use the `Cursor.SetCursor()` function? If so can you show the line of code?

Comment: did not completely get that, there is only one script for me that provides works for the color picker, the declarations are being updated above, the motive is that there is a button in which on click should return the color where the cursor is, the error I am having is when there is a button click the color shown is not what is intended as per the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RectTransform.rect.width` and `RectTransform.rect.height` aren't actually in screen size pixels as opposed to `Input.mousePosition`.`They are scaled with the canvace/screen, so that you always get a significant error with your correct formula.

You need to determine the global position of the corners and calculate the dimensions from that. Luckily there is a build in function for that.

```csharp
Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
Rect.GetWorldCorners(corners);
Vector2 dimensions = corners[2] - corners[0];
int localPosX = (int)(globalPosX * (ColorTexture.width / dimensions.x));
int localPosY = (int)(globalPosY * (ColorTexture.height / dimensions.y));
```

You also need to make sure that the pivot of the `rect` is set to (0,0) since the texture coordinates start from the bottom left.

Comment: @JoicePhilipThomas don't forget to mark the question as solved, so others know